# Redis Enterprise operator for k8s

Tags: kubernetes, redis, devops, amazon-eks, minikube

I'm facing an issue with redis enterprise, anyone can help me?
I followed the docs but I'm stuck [at this point](https://docs.redis.com/latest/kubernetes/deployment/quick-start/#deploy-the-operator-bundle): after the apply command I get only "Back-off restarting failed container" error. Logs from the pod return output only for the **admission** container, the only running. No logs return from **redis-enterprise-operator** container, the one in the *CrashLoopBackOff* state.

What am I missing?

I tried the command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RedisLabs/redis-enterprise-k8s-docs/v6.4.2-4/bundle.yaml -n redis
```

both in Minikube (with k8s 1.25 and 1.24) and in EKS (with k8s 1.25), and this is the outuput:

```
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/redis-enterprise-operator created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/redis-enterprise-operator created
serviceaccount/redis-enterprise-operator created
service/admission created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/redisenterpriseclusters.app.redislabs.com configured
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/redisenterprisedatabases.app.redislabs.com configured
deployment.apps/redis-enterprise-operator created
```

Checking resources, this is the state:

```
kubectl get all -n redis

NAME                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
pod/redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459-mcqdt   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (113s ago)   8m17s

NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/admission   ClusterIP   10.105.61.55   <none>        443/TCP   8m59s

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/redis-enterprise-operator   0/1     1            0           8m18s

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459   1         1         0       8m18s
```

I read [here](https://docs.redis.com/latest/kubernetes/reference/supported_k8s_distributions/) the supported k8s versions and it seems Minikube can support the image I've chosen. On the other hand EKS is not yet supported with k8s 1.25 so a kind of error was expected. The problem is that it occurs even on Minikube. So, is this the actual issue? Is there anything else wrong?

EDIT:
I paste here also the output of this command:

```
kubectl get pod/redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459-mcqdt -o yaml -n redis
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-30T07:30:56Z"
  generateName: redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459-
  labels:
    app: redis-enterprise
    name: redis-enterprise-operator
    pod-template-hash: 59d9688459
  name: redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459-mcqdt
  namespace: redis
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459
    uid: bf58858c-8e0b-4adc-b7ac-bb0b9f0a9b90
  resourceVersion: "1879"
  uid: cb1068a2-3e2d-4625-a175-faeda18f45bd
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - redis-enterprise-operator
    env:
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: WATCH_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: OPERATOR_NAME
      value: redis-enterprise-operator
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: operator-environment-config
        optional: true
    image: redislabs/operator:6.4.2-4
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    name: redis-enterprise-operator
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 512Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-46d6v
      readOnly: true
  - command:
    - /usr/local/bin/admission
    env:
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: WATCH_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: operator-environment-config
        optional: true
    image: redislabs/operator:6.4.2-4
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /liveness
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    name: admission
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8443
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 512Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-46d6v
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: minikube
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: redis-enterprise-operator
  serviceAccountName: redis-enterprise-operator
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-46d6v
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T07:30:56Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T07:30:56Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [redis-enterprise-operator]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T07:30:56Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [redis-enterprise-operator]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-30T07:30:56Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://5d6ab0bd54ed526329df3e6790059b48ef85014d2f9aab7d135257815d110806
    image: redislabs/operator:6.4.2-4
    imageID: docker-pullable://redislabs/operator@sha256:6f9c23fb667cd9c556a04d33de15aa4903028891db10e350dc8d787546c0ea37
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://594bf56135b0a7392cf59be67e14b94bc5a8a631d0b58b172b92d57740684896
        exitCode: 137
        finishedAt: "2023-03-30T08:30:30Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2023-03-30T08:25:08Z"
    name: admission
    ready: true
    restartCount: 8
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2023-03-30T08:30:39Z"
  - containerID: docker://ddd30597ed84a3509f684401f71db3397c9491b77e6695199de18ad1ccf102d5
    image: redislabs/operator:6.4.2-4
    imageID: docker-pullable://redislabs/operator@sha256:6f9c23fb667cd9c556a04d33de15aa4903028891db10e350dc8d787546c0ea37
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://ddd30597ed84a3509f684401f71db3397c9491b77e6695199de18ad1ccf102d5
        exitCode: 128
        finishedAt: "2023-03-30T08:28:55Z"
        message: 'failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
          failed: unable to start container process: error during container init:
          error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: failed to write "400000":
          write /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/kubepods/burstable/podcb1068a2-3e2d-4625-a175-faeda18f45bd/ddd30597ed84a3509f684401f71db3397c9491b77e6695199de18ad1ccf102d5/cpu.cfs_quota_us:
          invalid argument: unknown'
        reason: ContainerCannotRun
        startedAt: "2023-03-30T08:28:55Z"
    name: redis-enterprise-operator
    ready: false
    restartCount: 15
    started: false
    state:
      waiting:
        message: back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=redis-enterprise-operator
          pod=redis-enterprise-operator-59d9688459-mcqdt_redis(cb1068a2-3e2d-4625-a175-faeda18f45bd)
        reason: CrashLoopBackOff
  hostIP: 192.168.58.2
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.244.0.3
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.244.0.3
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2023-03-30T07:30:56Z"
```

Comment: Can you include the logs from the Redis container?

Comment: The CRI changed from Dockershim to containerd in EKS 1.25. It could be related, but it's hard to tell without additional information/logs.